# AppleEvents: Send port for process has no send right

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, xpc

I'm seeing this in my `Mac OS X Yosemite` Console:

```
AppleEvents: Send port for process has no send right, 
port=( port:30743/0x7817 rcv:1,send:0,d:0 limit:5)    
(findOrCreate()/AEMachUtils.cp #526) 
com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.1963
```

I'm developing an [XPC service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) that handles inter-process communication from a client `Mac OS App` running on the same `Mac`.

Obviously the error is coming from:

(`findOrCreate()` method of `/AEMachUtils.cp` #526 (Line #?)

The `XPC` service receives the request and calls the right methods to handle the request but each time I see the above warning.
The @protocol is:

```
 - (oneway void)doService:(NSString *)aString withReply:(void (^)(NSString *))reply;
```

I never see the reply `NSString` comeback.  Does the - (oneway `void`) have something to do with that?
The error appears in the `Console` tracking `stderr` for the`XPC`service.
Is the error saying that I need to give rights to the sender process?
If so how?

Thanks in advance for your consideration.
Regards,
AK

Comment: Do you have a firewall on? Your port could be denied.

Comment: I see this issue as well all the time with `DXFinderWindowServer` on 10.10.5 and my OS X firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apple's [Q&A 1888](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1888/_index.html).

Sending apple events requires a [scripting-targets entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW25), and from the error I suspect you don't have one.